# Background image resizing to fit landscape resolution as well as cropping for portrait resolutions

Tags: css, html, image

Is it possible to resize a background image based on whether the screen resolution is portrait or landscape?

For example, I have an image of what I want to achieve:  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMhic.png)

There is also an example of it on this site: [Cuberto](http://cuberto.com). Scroll to the work pages and resize the window. They are using a video. However, that is the desired effect I wish to achieve.

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" id="slide3"></div
```

CSS:

```
#slide3{
background-image: url(/images/3.jpg)no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;}
```

I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Do not set width, height, or margins.

Comment: I should have mate it clear before. I need the image to be full height at portrait resolution as well. This image (https://gyazo.com/311e066ad721d994b4a7267d939ca411) shows what im currently getting and what im trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using background images your container will be the 'window' that needs to do the resizing.

You can swap the `background-image` using a media query for `orientation`

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

[From W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)

EDIT: If you are using a plugin, this might be setting an inline height value based off the loaded image.